# Replacing number on the edges

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe with 0s and 127s only. The 127s are clumped together as given in the example.

```
df = DataFrame({'f1' : [0,0,0,0,0,0],
'f2' : [0,0,0,0,0,0],
'f3' : [0,0,127,127,0,0],
'f4' : [0,127,127,127,0,0],
'f5' : [0,127,127,127,127,0],
'f6' : [0,127,127,127,127,0],
'f7' : [0,0,127,127,127,0],
'f8' : [0,0,127,127,0,0],
'f9' : [0,0,127,0,0,0],
'f10' : [0,0,0,0,0,0]
})

    f1  f2   f3   f4   f5   f6   f7   f8   f9  f10
0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1   0   0    0  127  127  127    0    0    0    0
2   0   0  127  127  127  127  127  127  127    0
3   0   0  127  127  127  127  127  127    0    0
4   0   0    0    0  127  127  127    0    0    0
5   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Given a list of numbers `num_of_cells_to_del`, I want to randomly clear that many cells in a particular column `randomly from top or bottom`.

```
num_of_cells_to_del = [0,0,0,1,1,2,2,1,0,0]
```

Result:

```
        f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6  f7  f8  f9  f10
   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1    0   0   0   0   127 0   0   0   0   0
   2    0   0   127 127 127 0   0   0   127 0
   3    0   0   127 127 127 127 127 127 0   0
   4    0   0   0   0   0   127 0   0   0   0
   5    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not fully understand your example
Do you want to put 0's from top by column or from left by rows?
If first, then your result is not correct
If second, then you do not have enough values in num_of_cells_to_del

In any case, below code for both:

#### Input

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'f1' : [0,0,0,0,0,0],
'f2' : [0,0,0,0,0,0],
'f3' : [0,0,127,127,0,0],
'f4' : [0,127,127,127,0,0],
'f5' : [0,127,127,127,127,0],
'f6' : [0,127,127,127,127,0],
'f7' : [0,0,127,127,127,0],
'f8' : [0,0,127,127,0,0],
'f9' : [0,0,127,0,0,0],
'f10' : [0,0,0,0,0,0]
})
print(df)
   f1  f2   f3   f4   f5   f6   f7   f8   f9  f10
0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1   0   0    0  127  127  127    0    0    0    0
2   0   0  127  127  127  127  127  127  127    0
3   0   0  127  127  127  127  127  127    0    0
4   0   0    0    0  127  127  127    0    0    0
5   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
num_of_cells_to_del = [0,1,1,2,2,0]
```

#### 0's by rows

```
for i, r in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if i<len(num_of_cells_to_del):
        df.iloc[0:num_of_cells_to_del[i],i]=0
print(df)
   f1  f2   f3   f4   f5   f6   f7   f8   f9  f10
0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1   0   0    0    0    0  127    0    0    0    0
2   0   0  127  127  127  127  127  127  127    0
3   0   0  127  127  127  127  127  127    0    0
4   0   0    0    0  127  127  127    0    0    0
5   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

#### 0's by columns

```
for i, c in enumerate(df.keys()):
    if i<len(num_of_cells_to_del):
        df.loc[0:num_of_cells_to_del[i],c]=0
print(df)
   f1  f2   f3   f4   f5   f6   f7   f8   f9  f10
0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1   0   0    0    0    0  127    0    0    0    0
2   0   0  127    0    0  127  127  127  127    0
3   0   0  127  127  127  127  127  127    0    0
4   0   0    0    0  127  127  127    0    0    0
5   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

#### 0's by columns and randomly from top or bottom

```
for i, c in enumerate(df.keys()):
    if i<len(num_of_cells_to_del):
        if np.random.rand()>0.5:
            df.loc[0:num_of_cells_to_del[i],c]=0
        elif num_of_cells_to_del[i]>0:
            df.loc[-num_of_cells_to_del[i]:,c]=0
print(df)
   f1  f2   f3   f4   f5   f6   f7   f8   f9  f10
0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2   0   0  127  127  127    0    0  127  127    0
3   0   0  127  127  127  127  127  127    0    0
4   0   0    0    0  127  127  127    0    0    0
5   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: I updated the OP. Your solution looks good but the deletion is random, either from top ot bottom

Comment: Updated and added to select randomly top or bottom

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
for col, cells in zip(df.columns, num_of_cells_to_del):
  col_vals = df[col].values
  non_zero = np.where(col_vals == 127)[0] # find which indices have 127
  if len(non_zero) < cells: # can't delete more that what's present!
    raise Exception('Not enough 127 in the column!')
  if len(non_zero) == 0:
    continue
  replace_indices = np.random.choice(non_zero, size=cells, replace=False) # choose random indices to delete
  col_vals[replace_indices] = 0
  df[col] = col_vals
```